# Hyperledger Fabric 1.4 stopped working after migrating to Kubernetes 1.19, no working /var/run/docker.sock anymore

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, azure-aks, docker-in-docker

I have a problem on a running Hyperledger Fabric network 1.4 that was working OK on Azure Kubernetes 1.17 after migrating to 1.19.
The chaincode is no longer working and peer nodes shows error "cannot connect to Docker endpoint".

Looks like the connection between the peer nodes and the DinD daemon is dead now (I was using unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock ) as CORE_VM_ENDPOINT.

Is there any workaround? Maybe there is a way to go back to tcp://docker:2375 for the CORE_VM_ENDPOINT value?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AKS changed the container runtime from Docker to containerd some time ago. This is why the Docker socket isn't available anymore.

In September 2021 the Ubuntu 18.04 node images when GA. With those containerd got introduced. These node images are the default images when using or upgrading to Kubernetes 1.18.

Some more details:

- [containerd and AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-configuration#container-runtime-configuration)
- [Ubuntu 18.04 node image](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/ga-aks-support-for-new-base-image-ubuntu-1804/)